# Install zfsutils on debian bullseye on raspberry pi 4

Tags: debian, raspberry-pi, zfs

I'm running into an error installing zfsutils on Pi OS 64-bit upgraded to debian bullseye.

```
sudo apt install zfsutils-linux

The following packages have unmet dependencies:  zfsutils-linux : Depends: libnvpair3linux (= 2.0.3-9~bpo10+1) but 2.0.3-9 is to be installed
                  Depends: libuutil3linux (= 2.0.3-9~bpo10+1) but 2.0.3-9 is to be installed
                  Depends: libzfs4linux (= 2.0.3-9~bpo10+1) but 2.0.3-9 is to be installed
                  Depends: libzpool4linux (= 2.0.3-9~bpo10+1) but 2.0.3-9 is to be installed
                  Recommends: zfs-zed but it is not going to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

apt policy zfsutils-linux

zfsutils-linux:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.0.3-9~bpo10+1
  Version table:
     2.0.3-9 500
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/contrib arm64 Packages
     2.0.3-9~bpo10+1 990
        100 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports/contrib arm64 Packages
     2.0.2-1~bpo10+1 500
        500 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian buster/main arm64 Packages
     0.7.12-2+deb10u2 500
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/contrib arm64 Packages
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to show the output of `apt policy zfsutils-linux`?

Answer (score 0):

Needed to remove buster-backports from apt sources and update. zfsutils 2.0.3-9 installed fine after that.

Answer (score 0):

On an upgraded Raspberry Pi Os, from buster to bullseye, or on a fresh install of the Raspberry Pi OS to bullseye with kernel 5.15, there are no apt buster backports on my machines. And the dkms-zfs and zfsutils-linux are broken. Thus, ZFS doesn’t install on the Raspberry Pi OS as of 11/10/2022.

Answer (score 0):

ZFS still doesn't install on Raspberry Pi OS as of March 2023, see [here](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?p=2088988#p2088988) and the [original post](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?p=2088840#p2088840).